# How can you create a Cloudflare Durable Object in a pages project

Tags: cloudflare-workers, cloudflare-pages

I have a `Cloudflare Pages` project (Built with `Gatsby`) that I wish to add a `Durable Object` to. Right now I can add `workers` by putting them into the `functions` directory of the project.

`Cloudflare's` documentation indicates I should be able to add a binding through the `dashboard`, but there is no option to do so.

I have tried adding a custom `wrangler.toml` to the project, but it does not seem to have any effect.

How can I add a `Cloudflare Durable Object` to the project?

Comment: Have been trying to do this myself without luck. The only option I've found so far is to create a separate Worker for the Durable Object and then bind to that from the Pages project.

Comment: That's the approach I have taken in the mean time

Answer (score 0):

In the bindings, try setting like these:

```
{ name = "COORDINATOR", class_name = "BoardCoordinator", script_name="functions/board_coordinator.mts" }
```